# Can programs communicate back and forth using pipes?

Tags: c++

I'm looking at someone's idea for a project. The person wants to have two programs communicate through pipes. Here is my question. Would creating two programs that communicates with one another through pipes on the command line be possible?

Comment: No, pipes are by definition one-way only. If you want two-way communication through pipes, then you have to create two pipes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: "pipes", plural? I suppose the project proposer is aware of that.

Comment: The way understand pipes is that that it can be used to send input to another program only. I've not seen it where the program can send output back to the other program.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: On POSIX platforms (like Linux and OSX) it's very common to use the [`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) function to create a pair of pipes, then use [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to create a new process and in the child process and then use one of the [`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions to execute another program. This allows the parent process to both write to the standard input of the new program, and read from the standard output of the new program.

Comment: https://github.com/rmartinho/art/blob/master/nyan_cats.c%2B%2B

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Not with my cat allergy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be rather easy to have two programs communicate via pipes and set that up from the command line. E.g. on Linux:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/A
$ mkfifo /tmp/B
$ /bin/prog1 --inpipe /tmp/A --outpipe /tmp/B &
$ /bin/prog2 --inpipe /tmp/B --outpipe /tmp/A &
$ wait
```

Or if the programs just want to communicate through standard input and output:

```
$ /bin/prog1 < /tmp/A > /tmp/B &
$ /bin/prog2 < /tmp/B > /tmp/A &
```

Or you can even keep one of the pipes anonymous:

```
$ /bin/prog1 < /tmp/A | /bin/prog2 > /tmp/A
```

Comment: Thanks, so then, it is possible. Just one thing. Is redirection considered piping also?

Comment: @agentNil: I don't know how to answer that. It depends on who's doing the considering. What you have here are programs communicating through pipes, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes. I actually found this article. It states that piping is just a form of redirection. Thanks for answering. http://www.linfo.org/pipe.html